# ES6 class add object of functions

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6, es6-class

I'm trying to include an object of function as a static class properties, to call like myClass.setPayload[id].call(this, buffer).

Actually, i have this :

```
var setPayload = {
    0x01: function(buffer){...},
    0x0a: function (buffer) {...}
}

class myClass{
    constructor(buffer){
        ...
        setPayload[buffer[1]].call(this, buffer.slice(...))
    }
}
```

The objective is to suppress the nedd of constructor, so i try the following, that not work :

```
class myClass{
    static setPayload = {
         0x01: function(buffer){...},
         0x0a: function(buffer){...}
    }
}
```

Suggestions ?

Comment: Well fine, i will find another way

Comment: If you want some code to be called at instance construction why not have it in the constructor ? What's the real goal ?

Comment: @DenysSéguret not the same question, i asked about a object of function inclusion in a class...

Comment: And how is that different from a static field ?

Comment: yes, you're right, sorry

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Static is only used to define a method for a class - see [static - JavaScript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes/static)
You can either set:

```
MyClass.setPayLoad = ...

// or make a getter function:
class MyClass {
    static get setPayLoad() {
         return ....;
    }
}
```